# Hosting internet site on Sharepoint 2007 - questions about migrating to 2013

Tags: 2013

My company is hosting a website on SharePoint 2007 that has about 150 users accessing it.  We need to migrate to 2013 because the server it resides on is running Windows Server 2003, which wont be supported by Microsoft much longer.  Here are my questions:

Do we need to purchase a special version of SharePoint 2013?  One that is built specifically for handling outward facing Internet sites?

Regarding licenses/CALs for users who will access the site - do we need to buy any?  I've read that external users don't require licenses in SP 2013, but it's possible I may have misinterpreted what I read.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have purchased old license with SA (Software Assurance ) you may not need to purchase it again. But if you don't have SA you need to buy them. As I know you don't need to by license for external users.The best way to deal with the scenario is, speak to local Microsoft license specialist or your Microsoft partner to get the assistance.

More information about the upgrade :
Technically there is no SharePoint 2007 to 2013 direct upgrade. You need to 1st upgrade your SharePoint environment to SP2010 and then you have to upgrade it to SP2013